# How do you discover and Execute commands in a .Net vNext package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr

So curious about discovering and executing dnx commands programmatically. Currently I have a scheduling program that will scan a folder for Jobs using MEF and then create a new AppDomain and run any jobs found on some schedule and destroy the appdomain when done.

I want to convert all of the jobs to dnx console apps and find a way to scan a folder for all packages and their corresponding dnx commands so that they can be executed from the scheduling application as well as from the command line in a one off fashion.

It seems that there must be some library that is already doing this as Visual Studio can discover your commands and call them to debug them

Comment: have you tried a google search for the following `C# dnx console apps` http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. If you have a `project.json` file you can simply parse it and look for the `commands` property.
2. If you have a `nupkg` then you can look for `App` folder inside it. That will tell you which command are globally installable. However, there are a few commands that are ignored at pack time and they will not show up there. Take a look at the code for `dnu commands`: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/Install

The VS code that does that is not public but it's just option #1 (looking at the `project.json` file).

Comment: Seems like parsing the project.json files is the better option.  Is there a better alternative to using System.Diagnostics.Process to execute one of the commands?

Comment: Nope. That's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

DNX commands are just the name(s) of a Console Application(s) referenced by a given `project.json`.  `project.json`  then also lets you change the name that you use to refer to the referenced Console Application.  So the best way would be just to scan directories for `project.json` and grab the "commands" section.

If you are then interested in determining what arguments you can pass to the commands, well then that would be specific to how you have implemented those arguments/options inside your Console Application.